# jquery webcam take picture

Tags: jquery, html, web, webcam

im trying with the jquery plugin for webcam:
*http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/*
to take a picture.

this is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#camera").webcam({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            mode: "callback",
            swffile: "webcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf",



            onTick: function(remain) {

            if (0 == remain) {
                jQuery("#status").text("Cheese!");
            } else {
                jQuery("#status").text(remain + " seconds remaining...");
            }
            },



            onSave: function(data) {

            var col = data.split(";");
            var img = image;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
                var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
                img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
                img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
                pos+= 4;
            }

            if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240) {
                ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
                pos = 0;
            }
            },



            onCapture: function () {

            jQuery("#flash").css("display", "block");
            jQuery("#flash").fadeOut("fast", function () {
                    jQuery("#flash").css("opacity", 1);
            });

            webcam.save();
            },






            debug: function (type, string) {
            $("#status").html(type + ": " + string);
            },





            onLoad: function() {

            var cams = webcam.getCameraList();
            for(var i in cams) {
                jQuery("#cams").append("<li>" + cams[i] + "</li>");
            }
            }


    }); 

});
```

this is my html:

```
<div id="camera"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas>

<div class="menu"><a href="javascript:webcam.capture();changeFilter();void(0);"><p class="menutext">Maak foto</p></a></div>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'capture'
```

**someone know what i need to do?**

Comment: As it's mentioned in documentation "The onLoad callback is called as soon as the registration of the interface is done.".
I guess you need to make sure every things are loaded completely. You can check this problem in Firebug debug console and call capture function manually and see whether the problem is because of loading sequence or not.

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a solution to this?